# Alternative for com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil in HMS

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

Standard HMS converter does nothing to `SphericalUtil.computeOffset` (of `com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils`). At the same time it depends on 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng'. Is there an alternative in HMS world (for SphericalUtil, copy pasting from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils does not count)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Huawei there is opensource for doing spherical map function:

https://github.com/SupasinTatiyanupanwong/huawei-maps-utils

in here we can do Spherical geometry — for example: computeDistance, computeHeading, computeArea

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'me.tatiyanupanwong.supasin.android.libraries.huawei.maps:maps-utils:1.0.0-alpha02'
}
```

and do

```
double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(mMarkerA.getPosition(), mMarkerB.getPosition());
```